# Inner join in postgreSQL getting duplicate rows

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have 2 SQL query.

query 1

```
select file_number_fk,sent_date as submitted_date from fl_file_movement 
where sent_by_post_fk='735' 
and file_number_fk='98223'
```

query 2

```
select file_number_fk,received_date as received_date from fl_file_movement 
where recipient_post_fk='735' 
and file_number_fk='98223'
```

each query return a table with 7 rows
when i try to join them i getting 49 rows

```
select distinct  a.file_number_fk,
       a.received_date,
       b.submitted_date from(
       select file_number_fk,received_date as received_date from fl_file_movement 
where recipient_post_fk='735' 
and file_number_fk='98223')a LEFT JOIN (
select file_number_fk,sent_date as submitted_date from fl_file_movement 
where sent_by_post_fk='735' 
and file_number_fk='98223')b ON a.file_number_fk=b.file_number_fk
```

i want a joined table with 7 rows. how to do this

Comment: Try adding `GROUP BY` .

Comment: Your question is hard to answer without seeing the exact data. Please show: 1) result of queries 1 and 2, and 2) desired result of join.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `JOIN` condition is not specific enough, as both of your query have equal on two fields and your `JOIN` has equal on only one of them, thus multiplying the result:

```
select distinct  a.file_number_fk, a.received_date, b.submitted_date 
from (select file_number_fk, received_date as received_date 
        from fl_file_movement 
        where recipient_post_fk='735' and file_number_fk='98223') a 
LEFT JOIN (
        select file_number_fk,sent_date as submitted_date 
        from fl_file_movement 
        where sent_by_post_fk='735' 
        and file_number_fk='98223') b 
    ON a.file_number_fk=b.file_number_fk AND a.recipient_post_fk = b.file_number_fk
```

The above query is basically what you have provided + extra `JOIN` condition + improved readability. I think that `DISTINCT` can be removed in this case.

Also, you can also solve this with `SELF JOIN`. Something like this:

```
SELECT src.file_number_fk, src.received_date, dest.submitted_date
FROM fl_file_movement src
   JOIN fl_file_movement dest ON dest.recipient_post_fk = src.sent_by_post_fk and src.file_number_fk = dest.file_number_fk 
WHERE dest.recipient_post_fk = '735' AND src.file_number_fk = '98223'
```

Comment: thanks.. but it doesn't work, i getting 49 rows for executing this query